# Finding the optimal solution of a specific parametric performance index with constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, optimal-control, constraints

Consider the following performance index:
$$J=\cfrac{1}{2}u_1^2+\cfrac{1}{2}u_2^2+\cfrac{1}{2}u_3^2+p_1\cdot u_1+p_2\cdot u_2+p_3\cdot u_3$$
Suppose $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ are the design variables and $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ are the parameters of the problem. Additionaly, $u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2\leq\bar{u}$ and $p_1^2+p_2^2+p_3^2\geq\bar{u}$ where $\bar{u}$ is a constant parameter.

How to find an analytical solution for $\min_{u_1,u_2,u_3}J$ by considering the above-mentioned constraints and definitions? Does it have any unique non-trivial solution?

```
This kind of problem may arise in constrained optimal control problems.
```

**Example:** For the following bounded input optimal control problem 
$$\dot{z}=Az+u; \|u\|\leq\bar{u}$$
with the performance index $V=\cfrac{1}{2}\int{(u^Tu)}dt$ the optimal control command $u^*$ can be found by considering Hamiltonian $\mathscr{H}(u)=\cfrac{1}{2}u^Tu+p^T(Az+u)$. Since the control variable is bounded then it should be found so that $\mathscr{H}(u^*)<\mathscr{H}(u)$ for $z^*$, $p^*$ and all $u$. This leads to:
$$\cfrac{1}{2}{u^*}^T{u^*}+{p^*}^T{u^*}<\cfrac{1}{2}u^Tu+{p^*}^Tu$$

If the control was unbounded the solution would be $u^*=-p^*$. For the problem with bounded control variable, $u^*=-p^*$ is also the solution when $\|p\|<\bar{u}$. **What is the solution when $\|p\|\geq\bar{u}$?**

Comment: I think this problem is a Quadratic Programming with constrained parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $J(u) = {1 \over 2} u^T u + p^T u = {1 \over 2} (\|u+p\|^2 - \|p\|^2)$.

We look for solutions of
$\min \{ {1 \over 2 } \|u+p\|^2 | \|u\|^2 \le \bar{u} \}$, or letting $x=u+p$, the equivalent
$\min \{ \|x\|^2 | \|x-p\| \le \bar{u} \} = \min_{x \in \bar{B}(p,\bar{u})} \|x\|^2$.

It is straightforward to see that the unique solution of the latter problem is given
by $x^* = 0$, if $\|p\| \le \bar{u}$ and $x^*= (1-{\bar{u} \over \|p\|}) p$, if $\|p\| > \bar{u}$.

Hence the solution is $u^*= x^*-p$.
Explicitly, the solution is $u^* = -p$, if $\|p\| \le \bar{u}$ and $u^*=-{\bar{u} \over \|p\|} p$, if $\|p\| > \bar{u}$.

Nearest point computations appear in many guises in optimization.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It seems alright. I have added an optimal control example. But, for $\|p\|<\bar{u}$ the solution for the optimal control problem is $u^*=-p$ which is different than what you suggested ($u^*=0$). In this case, the solution is trivial, from a control problem point of view. How could it be interpreted? @copper.hat

Comment: I made a mistake above when computing x*, I will fix it when I get to my laptop.

Comment: I repaired the computation.

Comment: many thanks dear friend

Comment: @MehdiMoghadasian: Delighted to be able to help!